# Install vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I have created vb.net 2005 set up project for a my customer. when i run the setup.exe it is in a windows xp machine it prompts a message as "An error occured while downloading a required file. you may retry downloading the file or cancel the setup. " 
when i check in the install log file the last details as below
"Downloading failed with HRESULT=-2147024891"

this happens in only a one pc which is xp installed and in other xp machines the setup is run successfully. Also .net framework 4 is installed in this pc.

please help me on this issue..

Comment: If its an MSI package, you may have an outdated MSI installer on there...?

Comment: what can i do for this?/

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=8483

Comment: Great. @KashishArora, I think the question fits perfectly, as it is related to deploying your developed app.

Answer (score 0):

If its an MSI package, you may have an outdated MSI installer on there...?.

use this link to get an updated MSI installer.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=8483